# How to prove that $(0,1]$ is equinumerous to $(0,1)$

Tags: functions

So obviously the only difference between them is that $(0,1]$ includes the $1$. So my function so far is

$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            1 & \quad ? \\
            x & \quad x \neq 1
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

I am not sure how to account for $1$ since everything is accounted every value is mapped...

are these even equinumerous to begin with?

Thank you.

Comment: Regarding the last question, certainly they are equinumerous. The map $x \mapsto x/2$ is an injection from $(0,1]$ to $(0,1)$, and the map $x \mapsto x$ is an injection from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1]$. Therefore, by the [Schroeder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem), there exists a bijection between the two sets. Finding an explicit bijection requires a clever trick - see the hint given by Siong Thye Goh below.

Comment: Im new to this, I don't know any of the clever tricks for this.. What is it if you don't mind me asking? I am not fully understanding it. I came up with x/2 as well is that not bijective?

Comment: No, $x/2$ is not a bijection in either direction, because it's not a surjection. For example, if you define $f : (0,1] \to (0,1)$ by $f(x) = x/2$, the image is $(0,1/2]$, so you fail to reach the points in $(1/2, 1)$.

Comment: To see the clever trick, consider the slightly simpler problem of mapping all of the **rationals** in $(0,1)$ bijectively to the **rationals** in $(0,1]$. Start with an enumeration of the rationals in $(0,1)$. Then consider the map which inserts $1$ at the start of that sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Handle rational point separately from irrational point. For irrational point, send them to themselves.

Edit:

Let $f_1$ be a bijection from $(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{N}$ and $f_2$ be a bijection from $\mathbb{N} \to (0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q} .$

Then $g(x) = f_2 \circ f_1$ is a bijection from $(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q} \to (0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}.$

Let $h: (0,1) \to (0,1]$, where

$$h(x) = \begin{cases} x &, x \in (0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}^c\\
g(x) &, x \in (0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}. \end{cases}$$

Comment: What do you mean? as of now they all go to themselves except for 1. What do I do with 1 ?

Comment: think of a different mapping for rational point, don't map to themselves.

Comment: Ok let's say I  map everything to x/2? would that be sufficient?

Comment: hint: $(0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is countable, there is a bijection to $\mathbb{N}$, similiarly,$(0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

Comment: I have provided more details for a possible solution. There are other alternative approach as well.